# how to record audio from a URL (podcast, radio, stream) into file without using mic. Flutter plugin Just Audio

Tags: flutter, mp3, audio-streaming, just-audio, file-saver

I have a radio app where I play radio from URL using just audio in flutter (by using **seturl**() method and then **play**() method). I want to record audio using stream or **some sort of other way than using microphone** (which is already done and working).
Thanks.

And I need to save file as mp3.

I wonder maybe there is a stream which I can listen to get streaming audio as uint8list to save in file. Or any other way then recording with microphone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do this by reading audio stream as bytes then write these bytes to a file.

First import dio repo to handle reading audio stream as Stream of bytes.

[Check Dio Package](https://pub.dev/packages/dio)

then add this class to your project .. copy it from my gist

[Record Class](https://gist.github.com/drahmedgabr/da506a770ed494ac0ed0739b1c089ccc)

and simply use it by

**Start recording:**

```
Record.start('stream url);
```

**Stop recording:**

```
Record.stop();
```